# How can I select multiple windows to tile in Window 7 (like you could in previous versions)?

Tags: windows-7, window

I've disabled Aero Snap, is there any way to restore the old method of window arrangement allowing you to do side by side, or top and bottom, etc.?

All you had to do before is select the windows you want and right click. I know the menu is still there in Windows 7 but it is only for the whole Task Bar, and you can also do it from the Task Manager but that is more complex to get too.

After looking all around I cannot find a way to restore any such right click menu for each application.

Is there a way to tile like this for individual windows or groups?

Answer (score 2):

One trick you can do that works for me:

1. Minimize all the windows I don't want included
2. Right-click a blank area of the taskbar and click **Show windows Side by Side**
3. ???
4. PROFIT (through efficient working)

Answer (score 0):

I use the key shortcuts a lot, particularly win+arrow left and right, to shift windows to full height on the left or right - also steps them across to the next monitor quickly.
Thats what I most often use to get two explorer views side by side.